# PHP - Assign some class to li tag based on some condition inside loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have following `Two-dimensional` array:

```
$data = array
(
    array("1.2"),
    array("2.5"),
    array("4.7"),
    array("5.7"),
    array("3.5"),
    array("7.2"),
    array("4.7"),
    array("3.5")
);
```

Now I am displaying my records through loop:

```
<ul>
    <?php
        for($i=0; $i<count($data); $i++):
            ?>
                <li><?php echo $data[$i][0]; ?></li>
            <?php
        endfor;
    ?>
</ul>
```

and this is the result:

[image: Default]

Now I want to check some condition inside loop and add `class="red"` to li.

Example 1:

If `4.7` found inside the loop, add `class="red"` to next all `li` tags.

[image: First condition]

Example 2:

If `3.5` found inside the loop, add `class="red"` to next all `li` tags.

[image: Second condition]

Example 3:

If `5.7` found inside the loop, add `class="red"` to next all `li` tags.

[image]

Any idea how to add class to li tags when some condition match.

Thanks.

Comment: check the value and add the class depending on value.

Comment: No. I want to do with `php` side.

Answer (score 1):

You can just switch on the class as soon as a matching item is found.

```
$switch_value = '4.7';                 // set the value where you want to switch colors
$class = '';                           // initialize the class to empty string
foreach ($data as $value) {
    echo "<li$class>$value[0]</li>";
    // set the class to red the first time the value is found
    if ($value[0] == $switch_value) $class = ' class="red"';
}
```

It's important to set the class *after* echoing the list item to get the output you want.

Answer (score 0):

Just check a condition with a value, and assign it

```
    <ul>
        <?php
            $isRed = false;
            $value_to_search = 3.5;
            for($i=0; $i<count($data); $i++):
                ?>
                    <li class="<?php echo ($isRed == true)?'redClass':'';"><?php echo $data[$i][0]; ?></li>
                <?php
                if($data[$i][0] == $value_to_search )
                   $isRed = true;
            endfor;
        ?>
    </ul>
```

Comment: All li tags are displaying as green background-color.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
<ul>
    <?php
        $class = ''; $num = 4.7;
        for($i=0; $i<count($data); $i++):
            ?>
                <li class='<?php echo $class; ?>'><?php echo $data[$i][0]; ?></li>
            <?php
             if( $data[$i][0] == $num ) $class = 'red';
        endfor;
    ?>
</ul>
```

Just change the `$num` to desired value programmatically.

Edit: move the `if` block to end of `for` block to leave the number's occurrence.

Comment: I have tried your code but I don't want to select `4.7` as red class. Check this `Example 1`,

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use something like:

```
<ul>
    <?php
        $red = false;
        for($i=0; $i<count($data); $i++){
            if($data[$i][0] == "3.5" or $data[$i][0] == "4.7" or $data[$i][0] == "5.7" or $red){
                echo "<li class=\"red\">{$data[$i][0]}</li>";
                $red = true;
            }else{
                echo "<li>{$data[$i][0]}</li>";
            }   
        }
     ?>
</ul>
```

---

**Output:**

```
<ul><li>1.2</li><li>2.5</li><li class="red">4.7</li><li class="red">5.7</li><li class="red">3.5</li><li class="red">7.2</li><li class="red">4.7</li><li class="red">3.5</li></ul>
```

---

**Ideone Demo**

http://ideone.com/s2gdmG

Comment: I don't want to user or condition and If I check with `3.5`, this tag display with red color. `7.2, 4.7, 3.5`.

Comment: Still not getting proper result. Can you please check my examples so you can get proper idea what I am trying to do.

Comment: What should be the proper result?

Comment: If i check with `3.5` this will be the result: `http://i.stack.imgur.com/uPZwO.png`